# Perform JPA query with LIKE operator on entity with enum (EnumType.STRING)

Tags: java, jpa

I am able to store, retrieve and query entities with enum types (using JPA/Hibernate). The enum fields are annotated with @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING).

Is it possible to do things like `"SELECT a FROM MyEntity a WHERE a.myEnum LIKE :param"` ?

The idea is to have it match any entity where the enum value string (in DB) matches a pattern like "SYSTEM_%" or "BUSINESS_%".

Thanks for helping out.

--- Update:

When I tried to query with this:

```
`@Query("SELECT e FROM MyEntity e WHERE e.myEnum LIKE :value")`
```

Using the values (to indicate match whatever...):

`%%`

I get this exception:

```
  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [%%] did not match expected type [mypackage.MyEntity$MyEnum]
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractQueryImpl.validateParameterBinding(AbstractQueryImpl.java:370)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractQueryImpl.registerParameterBinding(AbstractQueryImpl.java:343)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.setParameter(QueryImpl.java:374)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.setParameter(QueryImpl.java:71)
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to use like there and not =?

Comment: Yes I am. It is somewhat strange, but the purpose is to provide "simple search filter by partial value" of the enum's string value (as stored in db). So if user type "system" it should return only enums that starts with "system***".

Comment: I've updated my answer. I've tested this and it does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely. Just use `query.setString("param", "BUSINESS_%");`. Note that using `setParameter()` instead of `setString()` throws a ClassCastException as Hibernate tries to cast it to an enum, however `setString()` does exactly what you want.

Comment: I see, so this might work, but I cannot "test" this easily now as I am using Spring Data JPA > JPA > Hibernate. Will keep in mind, and if i get this validated, will tick your answer in the future. Thanks!

Comment: saidly there is a shortcut in the hibernateTemplat:

Comment: setString does not exist anymore

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem and I did the following:

- define a second attribute mapping to the same db column
- type of that attribute is String
- it is neither updateable nor insertable
- adapt the set methods of the enum attribute
- make the String attribute a readonly property

```
    @Column(name = "status")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private StatusEnum status;

    public void setStatus(StatusEnum status) {
        this.status = status;
        this.statusString = status.toString();
    }
    
    @Column(name ="status", updatable = false, insertable = false)
    private String statusString;
```

Now you can make queries using 'like' against the statusString:

```
TypedQuery<MyEntity> query = 
    em.createQuery("select e from MyEntity e where e.statusString like 'CLOSED%', MyEntity.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

saidly there is a shortcut in the org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate:

```
protected void applyNamedParameterToQuery(Query queryObject, String paramName, Object value)
        throws HibernateException {

    if (value instanceof Collection) {
        queryObject.setParameterList(paramName, (Collection) value);
    }
    else if (value instanceof Object[]) {
        queryObject.setParameterList(paramName, (Object[]) value);
    }
    else {
        queryObject.setParameter(paramName, value);
    }
}
```

would be greate if there is an extra else if (value instanceoff String)...

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you can build a query by concatenating pattern to the query.

```
em.createQuery("SELECT e FROM MyEntity e WHERE e.myEnum LIKE '" + pattern +"'")
```

It works with Hibernate as well as Eclipselink.

However don't try this with `pattern` made from user input because constructing queries this way is vulnerable to sql injection attack.

Comment: Tested with Hibernate 4.3.6.Final and Eclipselink 2.5.1

Answer (score 0):

None of the above answers worked for me, although I managed to find solution that worked for me and it's outrageously simple - you just cast your Enum to String:

```
   @Query("SELECT a FROM MyEntity a WHERE CAST(a.myEnum AS string) LIKE %?1%")
    List<MyEntity> findByParam(String param);
```

where "?1" is the param